# failed to load net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have stuck in a strange problem. I have a web form in which I am binding a repeater(child) inside repeater(parent) on databound of parent repeater. It works fine on my machine over the network. But at the client side, binding to the child repeater doesn't happen. I have checked in google chrome at the client side by inspecting element it shows me "net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" error but at my machine it doesn't show the same error.

I am binding the child repeater using following code

```
protected void parent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        try
        {
            HiddenField emid = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnemId");
            string id = emid.Value;
            DataTable dt = Employee.GetAllEmployee(int.Parse(emid.Value), 1);
            Repeater childrpt = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("child1");
            childrpt.DataSource = dt;
            childrpt.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment the "childrpt.DataBind();"  then page execution successfully completed with all the parent rows else only first parent row is bind and page loading stops some time later. This behaivour is experienced only on client's premises where as on my the page is executed as expected. There are no images in repeater.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this bug**](https://codereview.chromium.org/8496016), this error occurs when an external resource length does not match the `Content-Length` header given in the response.

Comment: if there is any image requested from server, make sure that its size is correct in the header